# The official size of the circumference for men’s NCAA basketballs is specified to be 30 inches. Variability in manufacturing produces ...

Tags: statistics

The official size of the circumference for men’s NCAA basketballs is specified to be 30 inches. Variability in manufacturing produces balls whose circumference are normally distributed with mean 30 inches and standard deviation 0.07 inches.

What circumference do the largest 50% of the basketballs possess?

- Using the calculator I got the Z to be 30 using InvNorm
- Then I used 30 = (x - 30)/(0.07)
- x = 458.57 inches

My math seems off but I do not know where. I think it might be a miscalculation with my Z score but I am not sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Something is certainly off. But probably not math.

Comment: The official size of men's basketball ball is 29.5 " (plus change), women's ball is a little smaller.

Comment: Are you asking what is the average circumference of the largest 50% or the minimum circumference of the largest 50%?

Comment: @copper.hat I have no idea what the question is asking either, that is how it is worded on my assignment.

Comment: If you don't understand the question it is too early to be doing a calculation.  I think it is badly written but you are asked for the minimum circumference of the largest $50\%$ of the balls.  In a normal distribution the median equals the mean.  The reason you have an enormous answer is because you divided by the standard deviation.  If the standard deviation were smaller, you would get a larger answer.  That is clearly wrong.

Comment: @RossMillikan How could I arrive at the correct answer using the same process I had already used? Or what other process could I use, I am really confused.

Comment: Given that the distribution is normal, the $50$ percentile is the mean.  The minimum circumference of the largest $50\%$ is then $30$ inches.